# How to run a snippet on breakpoint in developer tool

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm gonna ask a weird question:

Is there a way to run a code snippet on a breakpoint set on the DOM?

Use example:
- Visit a website with a table.
- Set a *Break On Subtree Modification*
- Run MySnippet when the breakpoint hits.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do though is set a conditional breakpoint with an `eval('...')` statement.

for example the following with log to the console:

> test 11:59:51:326

Good for checking timing issues...

```
eval('let current=new Date();console.log("test",current.getHours()+":"
+current.getMinutes()+":"+current.getSeconds()+":"
+current.getMilliseconds());')
```

you can also print a local object, e.g if **localVar** is defined:

```
eval('let current=new 
Date();console.log("test”,localVar,current.getHours()+":"
+current.getMinutes()+":"+current.getSeconds()+":"+current.getMilliseconds());')
```

Answer (score 1):

DevTools doesn't have this feature. After your DOM breakpoint triggers you can run a [Snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets) though. You can [run Snippets from the Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets#runcommandmenu).